# Setting up CORS policy for hybrid mobile web apps

Tags: asp.net, cordova, cors

I am developing a hybrid mobile application using Cordova, Ionic, and Angular frameworks. Using ASP.NET API as my backend. To be able to access my web API from the mobile app I need to set the CORS policy to allow all incoming requests (*). I am not sure if this would be good practice and safe when my app is on production?

I have searched about this topic and found nothing useful on Stackoverflow or any other website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to set the policy to wildcard. You can add the following rules depending on the Webview version / Capacitor or Cordova:

- Capacitor:

  ```
  .----------.-----------------------.
  | Platform |        Origin         |
  :----------+-----------------------:
  | iOS      | capacitor://localhost |
  :----------+-----------------------:
  | Android  | http://localhost      |
  '----------'-----------------------'

  Replace localhost with your own hostname if you have changed the default in the Capacitor config.
  ```
- Ionic WebView 3.x plugin on Cordova

  ```
  .----------.-------------------.
  | Platform |      Origin       |
  :----------+-------------------:
  | iOS      | ionic://localhost |
  :----------+-------------------:
  | Android  | http://localhost  |
  '----------'-------------------'

  Replace localhost with your own hostname if you have changed the default in the plugin config.
  ```
- Ionic WebView 2.x plugin on Cordova

  ```
  .----------.-----------------------.
  | Platform |        Origin         |
  :----------+-----------------------:
  | iOS      | http://localhost:8080 |
  :----------+-----------------------:
  | Android  | http://localhost:8080 |
  '----------'-----------------------'


  Replace port 8080 with your own if you have changed the default in the plugin config.
  ```
- Local development in the browser

  ```
  .----------.------------------------------------------------------.
  | Platform |                        Origin                        |
  :----------+------------------------------------------------------:
  | iOS      | http://localhost:8100 or http://YOUR_MACHINE_IP:8100 |
  :----------+------------------------------------------------------:
  | Android  | http://localhost:4200                                |
  '----------'------------------------------------------------------'

  Port numbers can be higher if you are serving multiple apps at the same time.
  ```

You can find more info [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors#solutions-for-cors-errors).